# Cannot Get Navbar to stretch across screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get my black navbar div to stretch completely across the screen. However, using width: 100% does change anything.

If anyone could give me advice on how to improve the way I created the navbar, it would be much appreciated.

https://codepen.io/vegetablecook/pen/qVgOPJ

```
HTML 

<div class = "container">
    <div class = "span12 text-center">
        <h1>Bill Gates</h1>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class = "container" id = "nav-container">
    <nav class = "navbar navbar-default">
    <ul class = "navbar-nav flex-row ">
      <li class = "nav-item"><a id = "special" href = "#"> Business Magnate</a></li>
      <li class = "nav-item"><a href = "#"> Investor</a></li>
      <li class = "nav-item"><a href = "#"> Philanthropist</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

CSS:

body { 
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.navbar-nav > li{
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}


#nav-container{
  background-color:black;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;

}  

#billgates-headshot{
  width:40%;
}
#row2{
  padding-top: 50px;
}
#billgates{
  padding-left: 50px;
}
#billgates-midspeech{
  width: 70%;
}
```

Comment: The restriction is a result of the maximum width declared on the element `.container` for the *media breakpoint* of `1200px`, e.g: `@media (min-width: 1200px)
_grid.scss:6
.container {
    max-width: 1140px;
}`

Answer (score 2):

The "container" class in bootstrap isn't made to be 100%. You want to use the "container-fluid" class to span across the viewport. I've made some small changes which can be found at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LeeMGy.

Documentation reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#overview-container

Use .container for a responsive fixed width container.

```
<div class="container">
  ...
</div>
```

Use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your use of the `container` class - if you inspect the element using your developer tools you'll see that the child container is being padded by the parent `container`.

Remove the nested containers or move your nav outside of the scope of your parent `container` to fix this.